# Unable to use CAST Function

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting

Im unable to execute a CAST Function in MS SQL Server when working with a DATE Expression.

```
 CAST(CAST('2012-10-01' - DateHired AS INTEGER) / 365 AS INTEGER
```

Error Msg;The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the subtract operator.

```
 DATEADD ( DAY, '2012-10-01' - DateHired)/ 365 AS YearsWithSchool
```

Error Msg; The dateadd function requires 3 argument(s).

And yes Ive attempted every logical Date & Time data types avbl...

Help is needed/ appreaciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use `DATEFROMPARTS` function to form a date, `DateDiff` to find the difference between two dates and finally `cast`(do you really have to??) your results to integer

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(day, DATEFROMPARTS(2012,10,1 ), DateHired)/365 AS INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction with strings will give you an error.

```
Select '2015-05-20' - '2015-05-19'
```

Error: The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Subtracting two dates will result in another date.

Try using datediff to get what you want, which is a number:

`datediff(day,  '2012-10-01' , DateHired) / 365`

The DATEADD function, as shown in your error message, takes three parameters and looks like this:

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

Unless you're adding a specific number to your date I'd use DATEDIFF.

Comment: Awesome Mark!! Your answer did the trick. I really appreciate the help.